# Openshift can not add node due to self-signed certification

Tags: openshift-origin

I am trying to add a node to my openshift master via openshift ansible playbooks. I try to add the node with the following command(it starts from systemd)

```
/usr/bin/docker run --name origin-node --rm --privileged --net=host --pid=host --env-file=/etc/sysconfig/origin-node -v /:/rootfs:ro -e CONFIG_FILE=${CONFIG_FILE} -e OPTIONS=${OPTIONS} -e HOST=/rootfs -e HOST_ETC=/host-etc -v /var/lib/origin:/var/lib/origin:rslave -v /etc/origin/node:/etc/origin/node -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v /etc/machine-id:/etc/machine-id:ro -v /run:/run -v /sys:/sys:rw -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker:ro -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules -v /etc/origin/openvswitch:/etc/openvswitch -v /etc/origin/sdn:/etc/openshift-sdn -v /etc/systemd/system:/host-etc/systemd/system -v /var/log:/var/log -v /dev:/dev $DOCKER_ADDTL_BIND_MOUNTS openshift/node
```

The problem is that the node can not fetch configuration from the master. I have tried to add the certificate with  CURL_CA_BUNDLE export, curl works but openshift still doesn't. Anyway, the error I get is this:

```
I0130 19:19:44.029170   76719 start_node.go:250] Reading node configuration from /etc/origin/node/node-config.yaml
F0130 19:19:44.041799   76719 start_node.go:139] cannot fetch "default" cluster network: Get https://10.4.254.28:8443/oapi/v1/clusternetworks/default: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Keep in mind that I also have trusted the certificate from the local OS, still no luck..

Comment: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#advanced-install-custom-certificates

Comment: Also, a node should be added by including it in the inventory.